# Unabel to Run BASH Script as Root in PHP Exec

Tags: php, bash, exec, sudo

I have edited the `sudoers` file to allow passwordless execution of the script in question:

```
wordpress ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/vgnadmin/createnewsite
Defaults:wordpress !requiretty
```

Here is the code which is supposed to execute the command:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $usernameerr == "" && $sitenameerr == "") {
$username=escapeshellarg($username);
$sitename=escapeshellarg($sitename);
exec("sudo /home/vgnadmin/createnewsite $username $sitename 2>&1", $output, $retval);
    if ($retval == 1) {
            echo "<h1>Script Failed.</h1><br>";
            echo "Error Message:<br>";
            foreach ($output as $line) {
                    echo "$line<br>";
            }
```

But upon entering form information and trying to run the script, I get the error message:

> sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Operation not permitted
>   sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I have checked the `journalctl -xe` to see if the command was even being run, or any errors produced server side and there are none. Am I missing something?

Other commands that are not `sudo` run just fine (ls for example).

Comment: Your webserver runs under a user account named `wordpress`?

Comment: Not the whole webserver, I use AssignUserID in Apache to set individual quota's for each site (I'm running multi-tenancy build). The command is executed as the 'wordpress' user though, I double checked by running exec("whoami").

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with that.  When that PHP code executes, Apache is running as the Linux user `wordpress`?  That would be something to check.

Comment: Yes Abra it is, I replaced the code with whoami and it returned the value "wordpress".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

> We use mpm-itk (version 2.4.7-02) with apache 2.4 and it works
>   perfectly. The only thing to consider here are the new configuration
>   directives
>
> ```
> LimitUIDRange
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> LimitGIDRange
> ```
>
> These directives define, which UIDs and GIDs mpm-itk can use (via
>   setuid/setguid). As you obviously want it to be able to become root,
>   your lower range must be ID 0. The following configuration will work
>   here:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
> LimitUIDRange 0 6000
> LimitGIDRange 0 6000
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> Be aware, the the upper border should include all user UID/GID
>   combinations that you want to use within your configuration via
>   AssignUserID.
>
> Note that you can configure this for each virtual host you have. Note
>   too, that you need a Linux kernel 3.5.0 or higher for this.
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/491624/setresuid-operation-not-permitted-when-calling-via-php

On RedHat flavours you will need to add the module manually to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (or wherever your conf file lies).

Answer (score 1):

Check you php.ini and search for **disable_functions**

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

If you exec not there, you are good.

Now check your permission/ownership of the files and directory where the command gonna make changes.
Update the ownership with apache or www-data user.
Changig file ownership.

As per your comment, the ownership is `wordpress apache`, try adding the user `wordpress`  to sudo.

Comment: Seems to be empty, should I add exec to the list?

Comment: The script needs to be run as root since it creates a new wordpress instance, which needs new users new quotas new files/directories and to change ownership of those files/directories.

Comment: [admin@v-wpmp ~]$ sudo ls -l /var/www/home/generatepage
total 12
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wordpress apache  365 Feb 13 15:18 completed.php
-rwxr--r-- 1 wordpress apache 3625 Feb 13 19:04 createnewsite
-rwxrwxrwx 1 wordpress apache 2699 Feb 13 19:44 form.php
[admin@v-wpmp ~]$ sudo ls -l /var/www/home

Comment: I don't see how that will solve the issue, as the script should be running all commands as root anyways? The wordpress user can't create users and set quota's so the directory is the least of my worries here.

Comment: Can you try adding your wordpress user to sudors ?

Comment: The wordpress user is in sudoers file set to run the script with NOPASSWD, which works in the shell just fine.